# how to Include a npm package in my npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-package

i am create a npm package and i want  [date-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date) package for my npm package how to include this package to my npm package,any way?

Comment: Isn't it enough to just mention it in package.json in `dependencies` section?

Comment: @Anatoly i think my npm package is for publishing, and how i include the date package to my package,how to do that?itspossible

Comment: Do you wish to include the whole code of date-npm? Why? If you indicate date-npm as a dependency then during someone installs your package there will be installed all dependencies as well.

Comment: @Anatoly just see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637054/how-to-merge-two-npm-packages-as-one   this is my actual problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just execute

```sh
npm install date-npm
```

in your package.

Once your package is published, anyone installing your package, like:

```sh
npm install your-groovy-package-here
```

will have `date-npm`, as well as any other dependencies your package might have, installed along with it.

Comment: date-npm is not an actual package FYI, should fix to have a proper response to the question.

Comment: @EdwardRomero: Perhaps you didn't read the actual question "i want `date-npm` package for my npm package how to include this package to my npm package,any way?". Whether or not `date-npm` is a package in the public NPM registry or not is irrelevant to the question or its answer.

Comment: date-npm in question above links to the proper package in registry that OP wanted FYI. But anyways, I just wanted to make sure future developers don’t try to run your commands and get errors and down vote the answer. So up to you to update or not.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re just building an npm library then just include **date** lib in your package.json dependencies. Once a user installs your lib, then npm will take care of the rest.