# How to merge two npm packages as one

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-package

I have created a new npm package. Let's say my new package name is my-package. I need to import [bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) npm package into my-package. How to import Bootstrap package into my-package? Also I need to change some color variables in bootstrap package to match my-package. When I do `npm install my-package` it should install my-package and bootstarp package as one package. I don't want to install my-package and bootstrap package separately but install or merge both packages as my-package. Any suggestions and thanks.

Comment: Would you mind specifying why it's necessary to avoid installing bootstrap as its own package? There's a chance we may be able to help you better given this information!

Comment: @Gershom I always need to change some color variables fonts and images in bootstrap package," in my package i rewrite the css and font colors, it's do for some group of people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question sounds like it is rooted in the difference between [dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies) and [peerDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies).

In the `package.json` for the `my-package` package, you can define `bootstrap` as either a `dependency` or `peerDependency`.

If `bootstrap` is included as a `peerDependency`, then it will require anyone who uses your package to also install bootstrap as well. This will result in their package tree looking like this:

```
➜  consumer npm ls
consumer@1.0.0 /private/tmp/consumer
├── bootstrap@4.5.2
├── jquery@3.5.1
├── my-package@^1.0.0
└── popper.js@1.16.1
```

Note how the consuming project is required to have a dependency for not only `my-package`, but also bootstrap and all the bootstrap peer dependencies as well.

To accomplish what you want, the `package.json` for the `my-package` lib should include those as its own dependencies. e.g.

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  }
  ...
}
```

By doing this, any project that consumes `my-package` will be able to specify only `my-package` as a dependency and all nested dependencies will be grabbed as well. Here is what the dependency tree looks like with the above:

```
➜  consumer npm ls
consumer@1.0.0 /private/tmp/consumer
└─┬ my-package@1.0.0 -> /private/tmp/my-package
  ├── bootstrap@4.5.2
  ├── jquery@3.5.1
  └── popper.js@1.16.1
```

---

As for changing the colors used for bootstrap, you can follow the theming documentation for the version you are using to accomplish this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming/